# Using Node.js to Optimize RequireJS in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: node.js, requirejs, amd

I apologize if this is a noob question.  I only discovered the concept of AMD, Node and RequireJS yesterday.  Been reading tutorials and testing with this all day and can't seem to get this to work.  Bottom line, when I run the command in the node.js command prompt I just get the three dots (...) and nothing else.  I have no idea what it's doing and/or why it's doing or not doing it.

Here is the current folder structure of my multi-page ASP.NET MVC project:

```
        -Project Root
            -scripts
                    -app
                        -home
                            -index.js
                        -common.js
                    -lib
                        -require.js
                        -jquery.js
                    -build.js
                    -r.js
```

Here is my build.js:

```
    ({
        appDir: '../../', //Project Root
        baseUrl: 'scripts', //Project Root/scripts
        dir: "../../scripts-build", //Project Root/scripts-build
        modules: [
        { name: "app/common" },
        { name: "app/home/index" }]
    });
```

From Visual Studio, I installed node.js from Nuget. I added node.exe as an External Tool.  When I open the node external tool, I get a command prompt.  I change the current working directory to my script folder

```
 process.chdir('C:/Project Root/scripts')
```

I then run from inside the scripts folder:

```
 node r.js -o build.js
```

Then I just see the three dots and nothing else.  The optimized file never appears in the scripts-build output directory and I never get an error

Answer (score 1):

I've just started looking into AMD, Node, RequireJs and r.js myself and hit the same problem. I'm not sure how you've set up Node but after some trial and error I have a working version that minifies and bundles my scripts correctly.

First I created a Tools folder and placed Node.exe and r.js in it. Then I created a Post-build event for the project like below:

```
$(SolutionDir)Tools\node.exe $(SolutionDir)Tools\r.js -o $(ProjectDir)app.build.js
```

Then every time you build your project your scripts get minified etc. Finally my app.build.js looks like this (you'll obviously need to edit this to suit your project structure):

```
({
    appDir: '../ProjectSource',
    baseUrl: 'backbone/account',
    dir: 'js_build',
    mainConfigFile: 'backbone/account/account.js',
    modules: [{
        name: 'account'
    }]
})
```

Note, my solution/project is structured as below

```
MyProject
    SolutionFile.sln
    Tools
        node.exe
        r.js
    ProjectSource
        app.build.js
        Backbone
            Account
                account.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a long time since you posted this question, but I see that there is still no approved answer.

Based on your folder structure I would suggest you to:
1. take r.js out of the project
2. move build.js to Project Root
3. Change "appDir" param in build.js to "./"
4. Change "baseUrl" param to "./scripts"
5. Change "dir" param to "./dist"

With those options it will create a folder called "dist" in Project Root where you will find the optimized files. In case there will be any errors while running the following command "r.js -o build.js" from Project Root in cmd, there might be dependencies in our js files that should be specified in build.js.

Note: "appDir" and "dir" parameter are used when the optimized files are moved in a new directory (destination directory) and they don't refer to your application source.